# Segmentation fault when using getline() in a loop

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault, getline

My code creates an array of 3 strings and attemps to populate each string using getline(). It also prints every string it gets:

```
int i;
size_t n = 100;
char (*words[3])[100];
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    getline(&words[i], &n, stdin);
    printf("%s\n",words[i] );
}
```

When I enter the third string in the command line I get a segmentation error.
What's more, if I replace 3 with 5, I get the segmentation fault when I enter the first string.

So 1) How can I get the program to store all 3 or 5 or whatever strings I give it?, and
2) Why if  I replace 3 with 5 I get the error on the first string?

Comment: You have a `*` in the declaration of `words`, which means there's one or more pointers involved, but you haven't made them point at anything.

Comment: I think that might actually be interpreted as a function pointer as well.

Comment: @n.m. `getline` will do this, if the pointer is initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: @SenselessCoder function pointers are indicated by the presence of a parenthesized argument list

Comment: You should get a compiler message about calling `getline` with wrong arugment type

Comment: I compiled using gcc -ansi -pedantic -Werror and did not get an error

Comment: "and did not get an error"  Your gcc is probably too old, upgrade.

Comment: What is the wrong argument type?

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong, you just have to add -Wall. Always use at least -Wall. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/474004622d8b7d24). If you use -ansi, then `getline` is not available!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `words` as an array of pointer and initialize it to `NULL` according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline):

```
char *words[3] = {NULL};
```

http://ideone.com/GxV9qy

Comment: One thing that caused confusion is that the man page I read, running `man 3 getline` in a linux terminal is slighly different. It required `n` to be 0, while the man page you mention stated that `n` is ignored.